# jQuery.sheet console error - Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the jQuery.sheet plugin on my site to allow users to do analysis on products. I decided on jQuery.sheet because it allows for multiple sheets within a table and because it was just as editable as Microsoft Excel.

My current code is below (I am creating the sheet inline)

```
<div id="analysisSheet"></div>
    <script>
        $('#analysisSheet').sheet({
            buildSheet:true
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

As you can see I am using very basic code and yet I am getting the console error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined` and the table does not display at all, only the outline with no menus and nothing is clickable.

These are the includes that I have in my header (for reference I am using Codeigniter)

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/jQuery.sheet/jquery.sheet.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/jQuery.sheet/jquery.sheet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/jQuery.sheet/parser/formula/formula.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/jQuery.sheet/parser/tsv/tsv.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error or have any other recommendations for a similar plugin?

**EDIT:** I'm already using a number of other jQuery plugins on the site like Autocomplete and Datepicker so I have the necessary jQuery includes already working. The problem I'm having here is unique to jQuery.sheet

Comment: You must include jquery as well! https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Sorry I didn't make this clear but I'm already using a number of other jQuery plugins on the site like Autocomplete and Datepicker and they're working fine so I have that kind of stuff already included